# Query json dictionary data in SQL

Tags: sql, json, oracle

My CLOB field in a table contains JSON and looks as following:

```json
{"a":"value1", "b":"value2", "c":"value3"}
```

And I'm trying to write an SQL query to return a table with key and value fields like following:

```
key|value
---|------
a  |value1
b  |value2
c  |value3
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON_TABLE` and then `UNPIVOT` if you want the values in rows instead of columns:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN
         JSON_TABLE(
           t.value,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (
             a PATH '$.a',
             b PATH '$.b',
             c PATH '$.c'
           )
         ) p
)
UNPIVOT ( value FOR key IN ( a, b, c ) );
```

So for some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value CLOB CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (value IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '{"a":"value1", "b":"value2", "c":"value3"}' );
```

This outputs:

> ```
> KEY | VALUE 
> :-- | :-----
> A   | value1
> B   | value2
> C   | value3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a9c7c74af1f610922ff9656163e0141)*

---

If you want to do it dynamically then you can parse the JSON in PL/SQL and use `GET_KEYS` to get a collection of key names and then access the correct one by its position and correlate that to the value using `FOR ORDINALITY`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_key(
  pos  IN PLS_INTEGER,
  json IN CLOB
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
  doc_keys JSON_KEY_LIST;
BEGIN
  doc_keys := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE ( json ).GET_KEYS;
  RETURN doc_keys( pos );
END get_key;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT get_key( j.pos, t.value ) AS key,
       j.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$.*'
         COLUMNS (
           pos   FOR ORDINALITY,
           value PATH '$'
         )
       ) j;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> KEY | VALUE 
> :-- | :-----
> a   | value1
> b   | value2
> c   | value3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efeddb66427ef6aa2dc4d1150d112c5c)*