# How can I get value with key in JSON_DATAGUIDE (dynamically)

Tags: sql, json, oracle, parsing

JSON_DATAGUIDE gives me only keys not value like "$.a" . How can I get key-value pair that example in below.

```
select json_dataguide('{a:100, b:200, c:300}')
from   dual;

JSON_DATAGUIDE('{A:100,B:200,C:300}')                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"o:path":"$.a","type":"number","o:length":4},{"o:path":"$.b","type":"number","
o:length":4},{"o:path":"$.c","type":"number","o:length":4}]
```

I need like this as table:

```
Column Key, Column Value
    a           100
    b           200
    c           300
```

I want to find it without using `declare`,`begin` etc. Only Built-in function for example `json_table`,`json_dataguide`. I don't want to declare function or something.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be

```
declare
  j  JSON_OBJECT_T;
  i  NUMBER;
  k  JSON_KEY_LIST;
  CURSOR c_json IS
     SELECT '{a:100, b:200, c:300}' as myJsonCol from dual;
begin
  FOR rec IN c_json
  LOOP
     j := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(rec.myJsonCol);
     k := j.get_keys;
     dbms_output.put_line('KEY VAL');
     FOR i in 1..k.COUNT
     LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(k(i) || ' ' || j.get_Number(k(i)));
     END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Demo

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b51c157961ce507ef5f91c53acf25963)

Then you can store the result if you want in `sys_refcursor`, or even create a table function.

Comment: I want to find it without using declare,begin etc. Only Built-in function for example json_table,json_dataguide. I don't want to declare function or something.

Comment: For example, `json_table(json_dataguide, '$[*]' COLUMNS (keys VARCHAR2(128 CHAR) PATH '$."o:path"'))` gives me keys.

Comment: @samurai-jack07, that is why I said at the beginning of the answer that it was just an alternative. You could build a custom function based on it. I hope someone else can find a way to do it using build-in functions only.

Answer (score 1):

In later Oracle versions, you can include functions in a sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause of a `SELECT` statement. Then, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61347166/1509264):

```sql
WITH FUNCTION get_key(
    pos  IN PLS_INTEGER,
    json IN CLOB
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2 
  AS
    doc_keys JSON_KEY_LIST;
  BEGIN
    doc_keys := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE ( json ).GET_KEYS;
    RETURN doc_keys( pos );
  END get_key;
SELECT get_key( j.pos, t.value ) AS key,
       j.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$.*'
         COLUMNS (
           pos   FOR ORDINALITY,
           value PATH '$'
         )
       ) j;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value VARCHAR2(4000) CHECK (value IS JSON) );
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES ('{a:100, b:200, c:300}');
```

Outputs:

> | KEY | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | a | 100 |
> | b | 200 |
> | c | 300 |

---

> Only Built-in function for example `json_table`,`json_dataguide`

You are going to struggle with those limitations as:

- `JSON_QUERY` only allows literal values for the path; you cannot pass a dynamic path value.
- `JSON_TABLE` does appear to allow dynamic paths in the `COLUMNS` clause but does not return a value for those dynamic paths.

For example:

```sql
SELECT t.value AS json,
       SUBSTR(p.path, 3) AS key,
       JSON_QUERY(t.value, p.path) AS value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT JSON_DATAGUIDE(t.value) AS data
         FROM   DUAL
       ) d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT path
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  d.data,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS(
                    path VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$."o:path"'
                  )
                )
       ) p;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-40454: path expression not a literal
> ```

and:

```sql
SELECT t.value AS json,
       SUBSTR(p.path, 3) AS key,
       v.val AS value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT JSON_DATAGUIDE(t.value) AS data
         FROM   DUAL
       ) d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT path
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  d.data,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS(
                    path VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$."o:path"'
                  )
                )
       ) p
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT val
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  t.value,
                  '$'
                  COLUMNS(
                    val VARCHAR2(20) PATH p.path
                  )
                )
       ) v;
```

Outputs:

> | JSON | KEY | VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | {"a":100, "b":200, "c":300} | a | *<null>* |
> | {"a":100, "b":200, "c":300} | b | *<null>* |
> | {"a":100, "b":200, "c":300} | c | *<null>* |

Although the query works it does not dynamically get the value. (Note: The query would work if you use a literal path instead of a dynamic path.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=960ee076fa1e06cc0dea0e004e34d74f)*

Comment: How can I solve this problem using dynamic path to get  the value ? Is there alternative way for dynamic path. Literal path gives me only 100 for every value. it should be different for each value @MT0

Comment: @samurai-jack07 See the first part of my answer using the `get_keys` function (defined in the `SELECT` statement, so you do not need to create a function globally).