# Oracle 19c - ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

On Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 using this code:

```sql
SELECT get_key( j.pos, t.value ) AS key,
       j.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$.*'
         COLUMNS (
           pos   FOR ORDINALITY,
           value PATH '$'
         )
       ) j;
```

I found on [Query json dictionary data in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347003/query-json-dictionary-data-in-sql) doesn't work: it gives the error: `ORA-00904: "T"."VALUE": invalid identifier` but it works on fiddle.

Why doesn't this work on 19c?

Comment: Please check whether table_name (the one with alias t) has a column named "value"

Comment: Thanks @ekochergin that was it. Oracle should give better error messages :/

Comment: "Better error messages" than what? It told you exactly what to look at: the column name ("identifier") `VALUE` in the table aliased as `T` - what more did you need?

Comment: How about `Column value doesn't exist on table table_name`. Oracle errors are very hard to understand. Oracle database exists since 1979, they had enough time to do it well, but it still lacks in many aspects.

Comment: Agree with mathguy. I look at that error and know exactly what it means and where to look. The same with most Oracle messages. If you need more information on one then Google it. You will get more than you ever wanted to know..