# JSON extract and store in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I want to extract the sample JSON below and store it in a table:

```json
"Employment":{
  "Applicant1stJob":{
    "StartDate":"2015-09-28",
    "Employer":{
      "ZipCode":"123",
      "Telephone":"11111111",
      "Street":" 1st job street ",
      "State":"NY",
      "Name":"Employer 1",
      "City":"New York"
    }
  },
  "Applicant2ndJob":{
    "StartDate":"2018-09-28",
    "Employer":{
      "ZipCode":"345",
      "Telephone":"222222222",
      "Street":"1st job street",
      "State":"NY",
      "Name":"Employer 2",
      "City":"New York"
    }
  }
}
```

I coudn't able to find a way to extract the JSON keys (Applicant1stJob ,Applicant2ndJob )into oracle table

I want to store it like below:

| job_type | start_date | employer_name | employer_zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Applicant1stJob | 2015-09-28 | Employer 1 | 123 |
| Applicant2ndJob | 2018-09-28 | Employer 2 | 345 |

Thanks in Advance

Comment: maybe it's my inexperience with JSON's, but comparing what you have here compared to other json strings I've seen/worked with . I feel like your JSON string is malformed and hence messing things up.

Comment: **Hint** : `JSON_TABLE()`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I don't think that will get dynamic object keys.

Comment: I already didn't assert that to be in the dynamic manner @MT0

Comment: Thanks everyone  for taking time and read and respond to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data (json CLOB);

CREATE TABLE table_name (
  job_type   VARCHAR2(100),
  start_date DATE,
  employer_name VARCHAR2(100),
  employer_zip VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO data(json) VALUES (
  '{
"Employment":{
  "Applicant1stJob":{
    "StartDate":"2015-09-28",
    "Employer":{
      "ZipCode":"123",
      "Telephone":"11111111",
      "Street":" 1st job street ",
      "State":"NY",
      "Name":"Employer 1",
      "City":"New York"
    }
  },
  "Applicant2ndJob":{
    "StartDate":"2018-09-28",
    "Employer":{
      "ZipCode":"345",
      "Telephone":"222222222",
      "Street":"1st job street",
      "State":"NY",
      "Name":"Employer 2",
      "City":"New York"
    }
  }
}
}'
);
```

*Note: Your JSON is invalid as it is missing the surrounding `{}` braces.*

Then you can [create a function to dynamically get a key of a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61347166/1509264):

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_key(
  pos  IN PLS_INTEGER,
  json IN CLOB
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
  doc_keys JSON_KEY_LIST;
BEGIN
  doc_keys := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE ( json ).GET_KEYS;
  RETURN doc_keys( pos );
END get_key;
/
```

And you can use it and `JSON_TABLE` to extract and insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (job_type, start_date, employer_name, employer_zip)
SELECT get_key(j.pos, j.employment) AS job_type,
       j.start_date,
       j.employer_name,
       j.employer_zip
FROM   data d
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         d.json,
         '$.Employment'
         COLUMNS (
           employment CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$',
           NESTED PATH '$.*' COLUMNS (
             pos           FOR ORDINALITY,
             start_date    DATE          PATH '$.StartDate',
             employer_name VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Employer.Name',
             employer_zip  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Employer.ZipCode'
           )
         )
       ) j;
```

Then the table contains:

| JOB_TYPE | START_DATE | EMPLOYER_NAME | EMPLOYER_ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Applicant1stJob | 2015-09-28 00:00:00 | Employer 1 | 123 |
| Applicant2ndJob | 2018-09-28 00:00:00 | Employer 2 | 345 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZN-7DN1I)